# Why does my KeyPressEvent not work with Right/Left/Up/Down?

Tags: c#, keypress

In C#, I am trying to see if the user presses the right key so that a player moves right, but when I try it, it does not register the keypress:

```
private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Right))
      {
              MessageBox.Show("Right Key");
      } 
}
```

It does not display the MessageBox

This doesn't work for Left/Up/Down either

However, if I replace it with

```
if(e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Space))
```

It works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's probably because `Right` is not a character. I believe you're looking for something pertaining to command keys.

Comment: I'd attach a debugger and see a) is the event even being fired? b) What the value of `e.KeyChar` is and c) what the value of `Keys.Right` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `KeyDown` event, e.g. for arrows:

```
private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
    }
}
```

Arrow keys are not characters, so `KeyPressed` is not used for them.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow Keys are in keyUp event they are:

Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Left, Keys.right

They are not triggered by KeyPressEventArgs.