# Press a C# Application button from keyboard

Tags: c#, keypress, keyboard-events

I have a sample C# Application which have 4 buttons like this:

[image]

I want when I press a UP button respective the others to be pressed the correspondent button from C# Application (when window is focused) and keeps being pressed simultaneously with keyboard. How to do this? I've tried with **KeyEventArgs** and **KeyPress** but I think I'm a little bit confused.

LE: And to have somewhat possibility to press 2 buttons simultaneously:

======================================================

Edit Later: I can't really understand. I've created a new project. The whole code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) { MessageBox.Show("|"); }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the whole code of new project, Why isn't showing te message box when press Up button from keybard? It is working for letters...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my KeyPressEvent not work with Right/Left/Up/Down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824451/why-does-my-keypressevent-not-work-with-right-left-up-down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Up, Down, Left and Right arrow keys do not trigger KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646998/1271037):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Right:
            button1.PerformClick();
            return true;
        case Keys.Left:
             //...
        default:
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. When press Keys (<>^v) is just moving focus to different buttons but it don't want to perform click... It works only for letters and not for < > ^, but the performed click is not visible. Is there any way to make is visible exactly like a click-press?

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyUp and KeyDown.  KeyPress events aren't triggered by the arrow keys.

[Why does my KeyPressEvent not work with Right/Left/Up/Down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824451/why-does-my-keypressevent-not-work-with-right-left-up-down)

**EDIT:** This works for me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) { MessageBox.Show("|"); }
    }
}
```